# how to limit the length of the questions using json array in android?

Tags: java, android, limit

hey guys i am developing a quiz where in i have 50 question stored and then i want it 10 questions only to display..the questions is randomly display..but my problem is it should be 10 questions to display in the quiz.please help me...help is really appreciated..

```
public class Question1 extends Activity {



Intent menu = null;
BufferedReader bReader = null;
static JSONArray quesList = null;
static int index = 50;



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.question10);

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1 * 1000);
                finish();
                loadQuestions();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Question1.this,
                        Question2.class);
                Question1.this.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();

}

private void loadQuestions() throws Exception {
    try {



        InputStream questions = this.getBaseContext().getResources()
                .openRawResource(R.raw.questions);
        bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(questions));
        StringBuilder quesString = new StringBuilder();
        String aJsonLine = null;
        while ((aJsonLine = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            quesString.append(aJsonLine);
        }

        Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), quesString.toString());
        JSONObject quesObj = new JSONObject(quesString.toString());
        quesList = quesObj.getJSONArray("Questions");
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),
                "Num Questions " + quesList.length());


    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        try {
            bReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("", e.getMessage().toString(), e.getCause());
        }

    }

}

public static JSONArray getQuesList()throws JSONException{

      Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = quesList.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
          int j = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
          // Simple swap
          Object object = quesList.get(j);
          quesList.put(j, quesList.get(i));
          quesList.put(i, object);
        }
        return quesList;


}
```

Comment: why have you called finsih() method in your onCreate method

Answer (score 2):

As you want to have dynamic 10 questions in every quiz, you can shuffle ArrayList by using `Collections.shuffle(YourList)` and take first 10 from that shuffled list.

But, as you are having JSONArray, you have to iterate it and prepare ArrayList, there way you would be able to use `shuffle()`.

### Update:

Refer answer of ogzd, there way you will be having **questions** as a `List<JsonObject>`, now you just call shuffle method as i have mentioned above:

```
Collections.shuffle(questions);
```

Now, it will shuffle the questions list so you have to copy or take first 10 items from it.

Comment: did you mean, im going to change the List<JsonObject> to Collections.shuffle(questions)?

Comment: @user2079544 **Don't do bombard, implement it and check**. It's Void method so it will not return anything but will shuffle your list.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 List<JsonObject> questions = new ArrayList<JsonObject>();
 int n = Math.min(10, quesList.length());
 for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     JsonObject question = quesList.getJsonObject(i);
     questions.add(question);
 }
```